# Redmine and SVN

Tags: apache, svn, redmine, webdav

I have problems letting Redmine know about my SVN repositories. In my project under "Repository", it says *"The entry or revision was not found in the repository."*

In the project configuration, I've set:

```
svn://my.ip/my_repos
```

However, I can work with Subversion anyway using ssh. I followed these steps:

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_to_handle_SVN_repositories_creation_and_access_control_with_Redmine

but this

```
install svnserve.wrapper /usr/local/bin
```

is not working for me (as root), it throws:

> install: Aufruf von stat für âsvnserve.wrapperâ nicht möglich: Datei
> oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden (No such file or Directory)

Answer (score 1):

> However I can work with Subversion anyway using ssh

Have you tried `svn+ssh://<username>@<server>/path/to/repo`  ?

> *"The entry or revision was not found in the repository."*

This can also happen, if there is no initial commit in the repository I think.